# Seaborn: create stacked histogram from list of tuples

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, histogram

I have a list of tuples that looks like the following:

```py
[(7, 7, 57, 192), (7, 7, 57, 192), (7, 7, 57, 192), (7, 7, 57, 192), (7, 7, 52, 192), (7, 7, 52, 192)]
```

I'd like to create stacked histograms for all the values in a tuple. For this case, there would be 4 colors of histogram bars (corresponding to each position in a tuple) and the x-axis will the frequency of occurrence of each number in that particular index. For example,

#### Colors

- Red (0)
- Blue (1)
- Green (2)
- Purple (3)

#### For the given colors:

- There should be a red bar of length 6 at x-axis value 7
- There would be a blue bar of length 6 at x-axis value 7 (stacked upon red)
- There would be a green bar of length 4 at x-axis value 57
- There would be a green bar of length 2 at x-axis value 52
- There would be a green bar of length 6 at x-axis value 192

How can I do this using seaborn without having to create separate lists for the 4 tuple positions or without creating a pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create histograms looping from last color to first color:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

data = [(7, 7, 57, 192), (7, 7, 57, 192), (7, 7, 57, 192), (7, 7, 57, 192), (7, 7, 52, 192), (7, 7, 52, 192)]
sns.set()
for i, color in enumerate(['red', 'blue', 'green', 'purple'][::-1]):
    sns.histplot([di for d in data for di in d[:4-i]], bins=np.arange(-0.5, 200), color=color)
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

PS: To make the code more independent of the length of the tuples, the colors could be retrieved from a colormap:

```py
n = len(data[0])
colors = plt.cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, n))
for i, color in enumerate(colors):
    sns.histplot([di for d in data for di in d[:n - i]], bins=np.arange(-0.5, 200), color=color)
```

Comment: yes it does. Is there some way to make the color assignment random as well? The idea is to not have to hardcode the colors.